# Unable to connect to 'Web3 Provider' on Remix using http connection

Tags: contract-development, remix, web3-providers

I am using an `http` connection to connect to the Web3 Provider using Remix. The port `8454` is listening as expected.

I am getting the following error:

`Not possible to connect to the Web3 provider. Make sure the provider is running and a connection is open (via IPC or RPC).`

You can see the error in the below image.

[image]

What is the possible solution for this? I need to use the Web3 Provider and not Injected Web3

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your test rpc's listening port is same as the port you entering into remix popup And,  also disable proxy settings in firewall..